# Kafka broker failed to consume messages through kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send() batch API

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka

I have written an application which streams event data stored in Cassandra and pushes to Kafka broker (version kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1), however in case Kafka broker is down read events keep on getting cached in a cached store in Cassandra and retried in a single call to send(). If Kafka broker is down for a long time this cache size increasing rapidly.

I have a situation where application is trying to send() more than 75000 messages to Kafka broker using:

```
class kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<K,V> {
...
    public void send(List<KeyedMessage<K,V>> messages);
...
}
```

However, it fails with below Exception:

```
kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
        at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:76)
        at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:42)
        at com.tfsc.ilabs.chronos.app.gen.event.pipeline.impl.KafkaEventProcessor.sendTuplesToKafka(KafkaEventProcessor.java:64)
        at com.tfsc.ilabs.chronos.app.gen.event.pipeline.processing.loader.impl.GenericTupleProcessingLoader.loadTuples(GenericTupleProcessingLoader.java:22)
        at com.tfsc.ilabs.chronos.processing.transactionmanager.impl.TransactionManager$TransactionManagerLoaderJob.run(TransactionManager.java:159)
        at com.tfsc.ilabs.core.trackingservice.TrackableRunnable.run(TrackableRunnable.java:21)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Another host which has fewer messages in its cache is able to write to Kafka broker without any issues so there is no installation or network issue.

Could someone explain if there is some limit in Kafka broker in terms the number of messages it could process in one invocation of above API function and suggest some solution for this issue.

Comment: are you getting these exception once you restart brokers ? as u said the size of cache increases once the broker is down ? what exactly is happening ?

Comment: Not on restart. I meant my application pushes data into Kafka broker, but in case Kafka broker is down/stopped my application caches the messages which have been tried for pushing so that I don't miss them. Application keep on trying pushing until they get pushed successfully. But more and more messages reach the cache and when they reach some size around 75000 Kafka broker throws exception (if it is up ofcourse).

Comment: Simply put the problem is just that Kafka broker is not persisting data when tried with a List of 75000 messages. Caching and all are my application specific details which you could ignore in general. I just want to know if there is some limit on Kafka broker end with respect to how many messages it could persist in one call, nothing else.